# Parallerperiod YTD MDX

Tags: mdx

I have MDX for YTD:

```
YTD( StrToMember(" [Time].[Year -  Month -  Date]   .&[" + Format(now(), "yyyy-MM-" + "01T00:00:00") + "]"))
```

And this works fine.

Now im trying to make YTD Last Year MDX so:

```
PARALLERPERIOD([Time].[Year -  Month -  Date].[Year],1,YTD)
```

But it is not working.

Any suggestions how i should proceed?

Comment: Um, you mean `PARALLELPERIOD` right? Assuming thats just a typo - you might want to describe what is actually "not working".

Comment: Sorry about being not too clear,

why i cant use that set (YTD) in creating of another set?

Comment: process will fail: 'function expects member and tuple was used'

Answer (score 0):

According to [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms145500.aspx), ParallelPeriod accepts Member_Expression as 3rd argument. That means you can use code like this:

- [Time].[Year -  Month -  Date].**CurrentMember**
- Tail(EXISTING [Time].[Year -  Month -  Date].[Year].allmembers,1).Item(0)
- YTD(Tail(EXISTING [Time].[Year -  Month -  Date].[Year].allmembers,1).Item(0)).Item(0)

But no way you can use SET expression or actual SET (i.e. {A:B} or axis reference) as ParallelPeriod argument

Answer (score 0):

Better choice will be to define your PY Measure as follows:

```
CREATE MEMBER CURRENTCUBE.[Measures].[Value PY] AS Null
```

and add this code to the script

```
([Measures].[Value PY] , [Time].[Year - Quarter - Month - Week - Day].MEMBERS) = Sum(Existing [Time].[Year - Quarter - Month - Week - Day].[Day].MEMBERS,  (ParallelPeriod([Time].[Year - Quarter - Month - Week - Day].[Year]), [Measures].[Value]))
```

This solution will work in all your queries and doesn't matter if you want to use single time member or set of the members on your query.